# Divergence of multiplication: what order?

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

Really quick question:

Suppose you're asked to calculate $\text{div}(f\cdot F)$ where $f$ is a scaler function and $F$ is a vector field (both depending on same variables). Do I just multiply $f$ and $F$ and then calculate $\text{div}$ or vice versa?

Comment: Multiply $f$ and $F$ and then calculate div. Parentheses indicate that what's inside them should be evaluated first (this is a very general rule about math notation).

Comment: yes multiply first. $\nabla \cdot (f \ F) = P f_x + f P_x + Q f_y + f Q_y + R f_z + f R_z \ $ where $ \ F = (P, Q, R)$